# Check if first column is populated but all other columns are null Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

Please what is the effective way for getting the rows where the first column (primary index) is populated but all other columns are null? The table has 25 columns and I want to avoid putting all column names in the WHERE clause.

Thanks.

Comment: Not possible.  You need to list out all columns or else write some dynamic SQL which generates such code.

Comment: Please can you give me a sample dynamic sql for this?

Comment: Only way to do dynamic SQL in Teradata is to use a stored procedure. Building your where clause manually will be much simpler.

Comment: I figured that too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One of many methods (this will give you a generated SQL to run, but you can amend the code just to get its results through insert select, for instance)

```
create table test_table_2000 ( charcol1 varchar(2000) );
replace procedure sp_find_blank_rows( in_database varchar(50), in_tablename varchar(50) )
begin
declare 
  l_sql varchar(2000);
declare  
  l_int integer;
  set l_sql = 'select * from '||in_database||'.'||in_tablename||' where 1=1 ';
  FOR fReq AS cReq CURSOR FOR 
        select * from Dbc.Columns where databaseName=in_database and TableName=in_tablename order by ColumnId
  DO
    IF l_int is null THEN
        SET l_sql = l_sql || ' and ' || fReq.ColumnName || ' is not null ';
    ELSE
        SET l_sql = l_sql || ' and ' || fReq.ColumnName || ' is null ';
    END IF;
    set l_int = 1;
  END FOR;
  insert into test_table_2000 values ( l_sql );
end;

call sp_find_blank_rows('<your_database>','<your_table>');
```